# Woocommerce quantity button disappear for a single unit in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-quantity

The quantity button does not appear next to add to cart when we have a single unit of product in the inventory. How to make it appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

This can be done with the following custom hooked function in `woocommerce_quantity_input_args` filter hook, where I target products with a a stock quantity of 1  on singe product pages only.

> **Explanations:** If you look [in woocommerce **source code** for quantity field](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.3/templates/global/quantity-input.php), you will see that `'min_value'` need to be different than  `'max_value'` to get the quantity field displayed.

So there is 2 alternatives to get the quantity field displayed:

**1) Setting an empty value to `'max_value'`** (that will allow to set any value in the field):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 20, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 1 && is_product() ){
        $args['max_value'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

---

**2) Set the min value to `0`** (but the quantity field can be set to zero in this case):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 20, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 1 && is_product() ){
        $args['min_value'] = 0;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

---

**3) The other way:**

> You can **enable back orders option** for each product… that will always display the quantity field.

[image]

Comment: Why is min quantity = 0? If I add a product by selecting qty=0, it is added to the cart with qty=1.

Comment: @uitwaa I have updated my code with another additional way. I have tried everything, but that are the only options (3 ways)…

Comment: Is there any way in which quantity remains fixed at 1 and it doesn't increase or decrease even if we click the arrow up/down buttons?
Thanks

Comment: Or should I find a plugin which will show drop down quantity with '1' item only?

Comment: @uitwaa WooCommerce remove the quantity field when min and max values are 1 so there is no way in which quantity remains fixed at 1 and it doesn't increase or decrease. Also there is no plugins allowing that, as nobody need it. So you can just forget it.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Comment: I have a small question. How can move my sidebar on the top? It automatically shifts at the bottom of page on smaller screens

Comment: @uitwaa This is about theming, and each theme is different… I am really not skilled in that… You should better ask a new question, providing a live link, the CSS that you have tried for this issue and all necessary details…

Comment: Okay, I've posted it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878962/sidebar-is-at-bottom-on-smaller-screens

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your function.php file:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Code should be placed in your theme functions.php file.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

[source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons/)

Comment: This is for the shop page.